# How can i extract more couples of "Key = val_1,...,val_n" in a String?

Tags: java, string, text-extraction

I need to solve a problem. I have a String of "rules" that has not always the same order, and i should extract the Key and the value/s of each key.
My Key/Value separator is the char "=", while the different couples separator is the char ";".
This string is composed of "Key_1 = Value_1, ... , Value_n; Key_2 = Value_1, ... , Value_n;".

Examples of my string is:

```
1) "Role = Student, Professor; HourFrom = 10:30; HourTo = 13:30;"
2) "HourFrom = 10:00; HourTo = 20:00;"
3) "Role = Professor; DayOfTheWeek = Monday, Friday;"
4) "DateFrom = 20/07/2020; DateTo = 19/08/2020;"
```

The possibilities are so many and the possible keys of my String are: Role, HourFrom, HourTo, DateFrom, DateTo, DayOfTheWeek. I guess I have something like 2^n combination, with n keys.

I'm really getting crazy, cause i don't have a string order so i don't know how to solve this problem. Hope you guys can help me, so thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You said that you have a problem, and you describe `rules`, but you don't actually say what you are trying to do. In order for people to provide good answers, you should explain better. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: @null_awe Sorry i'm new to post. I hope that now it's better explained what is my problem.

Comment: Why does the string order matter? You said you have 2^n combinations, but all you need to do is to extract the keys, so why does that matter? No problem about being new to the post, everybody started at some point :)

Comment: Idk, maybe with an ordered string it was more easy to expect what key/values i was extracting. But anyway i don't know how to extract them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split by ";" and ":" after put values in a Map like this :

```
    String input1 = "Role = Student, Professor; HourFrom = 10:30; HourTo = 13:30;";

    String[] input = input1.split(";");
    Map<String,String> output = new HashMap<>();
    for (String s:input ){
        String[] value = s.split("=");
        if(value.length == 2) {
            output.put(value[0],value[1]);
        }else if (value.length == 1){
            output.put(value[0],null);
        }
    }
    output.entrySet().forEach(entry->{
        System.out.println("{"+entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue()+"}");
    });
```

result :

{ HourFrom  =  10:30}
{ HourTo  =  13:30}
{Role  =  Student, Professor}

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Btw with this code i only have this Output: {Role = Student}.
I need to have something like: {Role = Student, Professor} {HourFrom = 10:30} ecc...

Comment: in your input you have an error (you set "," instead of ";" )

Comment: Thank you so much, i guess i will do another question in the next days, about how to insert this couple in the right fields, because i will need the data i extracted!

Comment: you are welcome , when you post your question please notify me in this comment , so i ll try to resolve it